# PHP não salva mensagem no XML

Tags: php, xml

Estou querendo montar um sistema de comentários, na hora de abrir o xml o php consegue, porém na hora de salvar uma nova mensagem não, além de não conseguir salvar ele também não da erro. (Obs: é meio urgente pro TCC). Códigos:

**pag_perfilAbertoTec.php**:

```
    // isso está dentro de uma div.
        $tipoUsuario = pegaTipoUsuario($conexao, $cpf);
        $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0", "ISO-8859-7");
        $root = lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfTec, $cpf, $tipoUsuario);
        $dom = $_SESSION['dom'];
        $ver = simplexml_import_dom($dom);
        foreach ($ver as $xml):
            if ($xml->cpf_origem == 1234) {
                echo '<p align="center">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
            } else if ($xml->cpf_origem == $cpf) {
                echo '<p align="right">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
                echo '<p align="right">' . $xml->data_envio . '</p>';
            } else {
                echo '<p align="left">' . $xml->mensagem . '</p>';
                echo '<p align="left">' . $xml->data_envio . '</p>';
            }
        endforeach;
    // Sim, está vindo post..

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $mensagem = $_POST['txtMsg'];
        $msg = addMensagem($dom, $mensagem, $cpf);
        $root->appendChild($msg);
        $dom->appendChild($root);
        # Para salvar o arquivo, descomente a linha
        $dom->save("contatos.xml");
        unset($_POST['txtMsg']);
        // estou usando js aqui porque o header está dando erro..
        echo '<script> window.location("pag_perfilAbertoTec.php"); </script>';
    }
```

**banco-mensagens.php**

```
function addMensagem($documento, $mensagem, $cpf_origem) {
    // criar msg
    $msg = $documento->createElement("msg");
    // criar nó data
    $data = date('j/n/Y H:i:s');
    $dataElm = $documento->createElement("data_envio", $data);
    // criar nó origem
    $cpf_origemElm = $documento->createElement("cpf_origem", $cpf_origem);
    // criar nó mensagem (texto)
    $mensagemElm = $documento->createElement("mensagem", $mensagem);

    $msg->appendChild($dataElm);
    $msg->appendChild($cpf_origemElm);
    $msg->appendChild($mensagemElm);
    return $msg;
}
//daqui vem o $root
function lerXML($dom, $conexao, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
        if ($tipo === 2) {
            $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
        } else {
            $sql = "select caminho_xml as xml from tbl_mensagem where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
        }
        $return = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_array($return, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $nomeArquivo = $row["xml"];
        if (!file_exists($nomeArquivo)) {
            $novonome = gerarNomeXML();
            guardarXML($conexao, $novonome, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo);
            $msg = addMensagem($dom, "Conectados!", null);
            // criando nó principal
            $root = $dom->createElement("mensagens");
            // adiciona a mensagem ao root
            $root->appendChild($msg);
            // adiciona o root ao xml
            $dom->appendChild($root);
            // retirar os espaços em branco
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            // gerar código ??
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $novonome;
            $dom->save($novonome);
            $_SESSION['dom'] = $dom;
            return $root;
        } else {
            // carrega o arquivo
            $dom->load($nomeArquivo);
            $_SESSION['nomeXML'] = $nomeArquivo;
            // recupera nó principal
            $root = $dom->documentElement;
            $_SESSION['dom'] = $dom;
            return $root;
        }
    }

 function guardarXML($conexao, $caminho, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo) {
if ($tipo == 2) {
    $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfTec and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfCli";
} else {
    $sql = "update tbl_mensagem set caminho_xml = '$caminho' where cpf_cliente_fk = $cpfCli and cpf_tecnico_fk = $cpfTec";
}
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: O que é `$root`? Qual é a atribuição para `$root`, como você fez no código pra preenchê-lo?

Comment: Editei e coloquei a função lerXML, que da onde vem o **$root**

Comment: Você não precisa fazer `$dom->appendChild($root);`; o `$root` já faz parte do `$dom`!

Comment: Eu tirei o _$dom->appendChild($root);_ porém continuou na mesma, o que posso fazer?

Comment: Tirou `$dom->appendChild($root);` de onde? pag_perfilAbertoTec.php?

Comment: Sim, de lá mesmo.

Comment: Você tá salvando no mesmo caminho que o arquivo xml de leitura, no sistema de arquivos?

Comment: Esse era o erro, acho que na hora de implementar o código no meu projeto, esqueci de mudar o caminho onde o arquivo é salvo. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Então você tem outro problema, a função esta retornando dados e você não esta usando o retorno. Você esta chamando a função `guardarXML($conexao, $novonome, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo);` o correto seria `$variavel = guardarXML($conexao, $novonome, $cpfCli, $cpfTec, $tipo);`

Comment: No caso aí você está dizendo para verificar se a função guardou no banco o nome do arquivo, certo? (Porque se for no caso para pegar o nome do arquivo, eu já tenho acesso a esse nome em uma linha antes). Trocando o caminho que o arquivo é salvo, eu consegui resolver o problema, porém apareceu outro, no caso o php não envia a mensagem que o usuário digitou, e sim uma outra. Enviei: "aa", a página recarregou e não apareceu, ao enviar "ab", apareceu o "aa", e assim sucessivamente, alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Comment: Teria que saber como você esta chamando a função `lerXML`

Comment: Editei e coloquei a parte que lê o XML quando a página é recarregada. (Está na mesma ordem que o meu arquivo, eu tentei inverter mas deu erro..)